# Kubernetes Networkpolicy does not work as expected

Tags: nginx, kubernetes, kubernetes-networkpolicy

I am fairly new to networkpolicies on Calico. I have created the following NetworkPolicy on my cluster:

```
apiVersion: networking.k8s.io/v1
kind: NetworkPolicy
metadata:
  name: nginxnp-po
  namespace: default
spec:
  podSelector:
    matchLabels:
      run: nginxnp
  policyTypes:
    - Ingress
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          acces: frontend
    ports: 
      - port: 80
```

This is how I read it: All pods that have the selector `run=nginxnp` are only accessible on port 80 from every pod that has the selector `access=frontend`.

Here is my nginx pod (with a running nginx in it):

```
$ kubectl get pods -l run=nginxnp
NAME                      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
nginxnp-9b49f4b8d-tkz6q   1/1     Running   0          36h
```

I created a busybox container like this:

```
$ kubectl run busybox --image=busybox --restart=Never --labels=access=frontend -- sleep 3600
```

I can see that it matches the selector `access=frontend`:

```
$ kubectl get pods -l access=frontend
NAME      READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
busybox   1/1     Running   0          6m30s
```

However when I exec into the busybox pod and try to wget the nginx pod, the connection is still refused.

I also tried setting an egress rule that allows the traffic the other way round, but this didn't do anything as well. As I understood networkpolicies: When no rule is set, nothing is blocked. Hence, when I set no egress rule, egress should not be blocked.

If I delete the networkpolicy it works. Any pointers are highly appreciated.

Comment: there is a typo in matchLabels => `acces: frontend` is it correct?

Comment: No, of course it is not. TLDR: Don't work on stuff if you are tired. I wasn't sure if I understood NetworkPolicies and though: Surely my understanding must be wrong...

Comment: You can use a nice tool by Tufin to visualise your network policies before applying them [here](https://orca.tufin.io/netpol/?yaml=apiVersion:%20networking.k8s.io%2Fv1%0Akind:%20NetworkPolicy%0Ametadata:%0A3name:%20nginxnp-po%0A3namespace:%20default%0Aspec:%0A3podSelector:%0A5matchLabels:%0A7run:%20nginxnp%0A3policyTypes:%0A5-%20Ingress%0A3ingress:%0A3-%20from:%0A5-%20podSelector:%0A9matchLabels:%0A11acces:%20frontend%0A5ports:%20%0A7-%20port:%2080)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There is a typo in the NetworkPolicy template `acces: frontend` should be `access: frontend`

```
  ingress:
  - from:
    - podSelector:
        matchLabels:
          acces: frontend
```